# Getting images off of S3 with CORS issues

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to get images off of AWS S3 and I am having CORS issues.

I am getting the error in my Cordova app on Android:

```
SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/#/: Line 0 : Access to image at 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com//wantify/merchants/56/logo.png' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is due to the following code:

```
  getColors(this.props.merchant.logo).then(colors => {
    var colorsHex = colors.map(color => color.hex());
    this.lightestColor(colorsHex);
  });
```

Now getColors is from the library `get-image-colors`, and so my understanding is that it is making a call on its own.

I am trying to figure out how to either ignore CORS or comply with CORS for S3.

My CORS settings are as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>localhost:8080</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8080</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

get-image-colors also allows a base64 buffer, but when I try that, I have no success either.

```
  getBase64(this.props.merchant.logo).then(function(base64) {
    console.log("axios base64");
    console.log(base64);
  });
  function getBase64(url) {
    return axios
      .get(url, {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        headers: {
          Origin: "Example"
        }
      })
      .then(response => new Buffer(response.data, "binary").toString("base64"));
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the image without CORS issues? I know that AWS requires the Origin header (which makes testing in Chrome a headache), but even when I include it, like in the base64 example above, it doesn't work.

How can I correctly get the image from AWS S3?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED : this is a wrong answer (see comments below) Amazon S3 does not accept OPTIONS as CORS action

It is very likely Axios will issue an OPTIONS request before the GET.  Be sure to add the OPTIONS operation to you CORS policy on Amazon S3,

For example :

```
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:8080</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
```

To further debug this I woud suggest to follow the steps described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html

Comment: My understanding was that S3 did not need an explicit use of OPTIONS, but I'll test it

Comment: Yeah, S3 does not support options: "Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is OPTIONS"

Comment: ok, good to know my API Gateway recipe does not apply to S3 :-)  I let you capture the full HTTP headers from the request and response, please post them in teh question for further debugging

Comment: But according to the doc, Aazon S3 does support preflight request (OPTIONS) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTOPTIONSobject.html (but not in CORS settings, you're correct https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Comment: The error message I wrote above is the exact error message that Amazon gave me when I tried to save OPTIONS under my allowed methods. I believe they support OPTIONS implicitly, not explicitly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to get request and response information from Android Studio - this is my first attempt at an Android app

Comment: You can use the Network Profiler in Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't know Android studio that well, I'm following the instructions and not getting the network requests. Sorry.